# Order of Contact for a general tangent line of a cubic threefold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am trying to solve Exercise 18.21 of Harris "Algebraic Geometry".

In the proof of the unirationality of a smooth cubic threefold X he claims that a general tangent line to X at a general point p $\in$ L, where L is a general line in X, has contact of order 2 with X at p.

I tried to yield a contradiction when assuming that the assertion i wrong by showing that in this case X cannot be smooth, but I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

(This was too long to leave as a comment.) Consider the morphism that associates to every point $p$ of $X$ the tangent hyperplane $H_p$ to $X$ at $p$, where $H_p$ is considered as a point in the dual projective space.  Either by the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem or some other computation, this morphism is finite to its image.  By Sard's Theorem / generic smoothness, this morphism is etale to its image at a general point $p$ of $X$.  If you write out what this means, you will see that the tangent hyperplane section $H_p \cap X$ is a cubic surface with an ordinary double point at $p$.  Thus, every line in $H_p$ that contains $p$ yet is not contained in the tangent quadric cone to $X\cap H_p$ at $p$ has contact of order $2$ with $X$ at $p$.